# Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory) exception on saving pdf file to phone xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On a click of a button I need to save pdf file.
Im using xf 4.6.1 and syncfusion component which has event - `PdfViewerControl_DocumentSaveInitiated`

In codebehind, when program should go to my renderer method `Save()` which is derivates from ISave class, it throws later on renderer method Save() => Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Download/SavedDocument.pdf (No such file or directory)' exception.

COdebehind:

```
        private void PdfViewerControl_DocumentSaveInitiated(object sender, Syncfusion.SfPdfViewer.XForms.DocumentSaveInitiatedEventArgs args)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<StoragePermission>();
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    status = await Utils.CheckPermissions(new Plugin.Permissions.StoragePermission());
                }

                if (status == Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    string filePath = DependencyService.Get<ISave>().Save(args.SaveStream as MemoryStream);
                    string message = "The Kiid document has been saved to " + filePath;
                    DependencyService.Get<IAlertView>().Show(message);
                }
            });
        }
```

Interface:

```
    public interface ISave
    {
        string Save(MemoryStream fileStream);
    }
```

AndroidRenderer:

```
public class SaveAndroid : ISave
    {
        public string Save(System.IO.MemoryStream stream)
        {
            string root = null;
            string fileName = "SavedDocument.pdf";
            if (Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageEmulated)
            {
                root = Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads.ToString();
            }
            Java.IO.File myDir = new Java.IO.File(root + "/Syncfusion");
            myDir.Mkdir();
            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(myDir, fileName);
            string filePath = file.Path;
            if (file.Exists()) file.Delete();
            Java.IO.FileOutputStream outs = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(file);
            outs.Write(stream.ToArray());
            var ab = file.Path;
            outs.Flush();
            outs.Close();
            return filePath;
        }
    }
```

On physical device, it goes to the method Save(), and it breaks on the line `Java.IO.FileOutputStream outs = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(file);`
As you can see I added permission check for storage.

What could be?

Comment: Post your error log please

Comment: @RubenMeiring I found the first issue with DepedencyServicy assembly thing, now I cant just save the file it says that path doesnt exists

Comment: you need to use DownloadManager if you want to write to the system Downloads folder

Comment: `Download/SavedDocument.pdf` That is a relative path. You should start using a full path.

Comment: `myDir.Mkdir();` Check the return value as it might fail. Dont continue if it returns false but display a toast and return. Only call Mkdir if the directory does not exists yet.

Comment: thanks guys! I will try and let you know what are the outcomes.

Comment: still I have same problem, even with absolute path...

Comment: Which absolute path? Please adapt your code here too.